# PHP find item with images and include at top

Tags: php, mysql

The first two if/elseif statements within the while loop is checking to see if an image exists for the news item, if it doesn't, it skips over it. The counter makes sure this is only done for the first three items at the top. Currently this works fine without any errors.

I'm wanting the top two if/elseif statements to only use posts with images ($row->imagelibid) - so there might be a news story 7 days ago with an image, so it uses that at the top - it's forced to find and use a news story with an image. This will mean the date order will be wrong for these 'selected' stories - but that's okay.

Hope that makes sense... and any help I appreciate.

```
$site_url = "http://www_#_com";
    $full_site_url = $site_url . "/" . $news_prefix . "news/" . $row->id;
    $news_prefix = "#";
    $adFrequency = 5;
    $ad = 0;
    $i = 0;

    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT news.*, regions.name AS territory FROM news JOIN country ON news.country = country.iso JOIN regions ON regions.id = country.region WHERE news.mobile_app != 0 AND news.hidden = 0 AND news.beef = 1 ORDER BY news.datein DESC LIMIT 20", $db );

    while ( ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) !== false ) {

    $imageid = intval( $row->imagelibid );
    $image_result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM imagelib WHERE id = {$imageid}", $db );
    $image_row = mysql_fetch_object( $image_result );
    $image_url = "http://www.#.com/slir/w280/imagelib/" . $image_row->id . "_" . $image_row->filename;

    if ($i <= 0 && !empty($row->imagelibid)) {

    echo '<div class="one-news-featured-article clearfix">';
    echo '<div class="grid_12">';
    echo '<div class="large-featured-image-container"><img src="'.$image_url.'">';  
    echo '<div><h2><a href="item-news.php?id='.$row->id.'">'.$row->title.'</a></h2></div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    }

    elseif ($i <= 2 && !empty($row->imagelibid)) {

    echo '<div class="one-news-featured-article clearfix">';
    echo '<div class="grid_6">';    
    echo '<div class="small-featured-image-container"><img src="'.$image_url.'">';  
    echo '<div><h2><a href="item-news.php?id='.$row->id.'">'.$row->title.'</a></h2></div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    }

    else {

    // Places ad based of predefined variable frequency
    if ($ad == $adFrequency){

     echo'<div class="one-advertisement-article clearfix">';
     echo'<div class="grid_9 suffix_2"><img src="http://placehold.it/263x75/000000/ffffff"></div>';
     echo'<div class="grid_1"><a class="navigate-right-icon ss-icon" href="#">navigateright</a></div>';
     echo'</div>';

     $ad = 0;
    }

    echo '<div class="one-news-article clearfix">';
    if( $row->imagelibid )
            {
                echo '<div class="grid_4"><a href="#"><img src="'.$image_url.'"></a></div>';        
            }
    else {
                echo '<div class="grid_4"><div class="news-placeholder"><span class="ss-icon">ellipsischat</span></div></div>';
        }

    echo '<div class="grid_7">';
    echo '<h2><a href="item-news.php?id='.$row->id.'">'.$row->title.'</a></h2>';

    $published_date = date('D, d M Y', strtotime($row->datein));
    echo '<p class="published-date">'.$published_date.'</p>';

    echo '<p class="news-snippet">'.$row->snippet.'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="grid_1">';
    echo '<div class="news-item-vertical-sep">&nbsp;</div>';
    echo '<p></p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    $ad++;

    }

    $i += 1;

    }
```

P.S I know mysql_ is a deprecated function, but if this could be overlooked for now that would be good.

Comment: Can you post your database table structures?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all the results, and if you find a image, save it to an array, lets say $newsWithImage, and if it doesn't find, it saves to another array, $newsWithoutImage.
When thats done, just loop through the first array and echo out the results, and then take the other array.

```
while ( ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) !== false )
{
   if($row->imagelibid)
      $newsWithImage[] = $row;
   else
      $newsWihtoutImage[] = $row;
}

foreach($newsWithImage as $news)
{
  // do your html output with the results 
}

foreach($newsWithoutImage as $news)
{
  // do your html output with results
}
```